# Alternative definition of matrix exponential

Tags: matlab, matrix-exponential

Suppose we have a matrix $X$. In some research papers matrix exponential is calculated as $V \times diag(exp(diag(D)))/V$ where $V = $ Eigenvectors of $X$ and $D$ = Eigenvalues of $X$. $diag$ means diagonalizing the matrix. $exp =$ element by element exponential. How is this definition of matrix exponential useful rather than directly exponentiating every element of matrix $X$.
Matlab also uses this definition of matrix exponential by its function $expm$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ the matrix exponential is defined as
$$\tag{1}\label{expA}
\exp(A)  = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!} = I + A + A^2/2 + \ldots.
$$
The matrix exponential plays a prominent role for systems of ODEs:
For an autonomous linear ODE system
$$\tag{2}\label{ODEA}
y'=A y~~~\text{with}~~~y=y(t)\in\mathbb{C}^n,~y(0)=y_0
$$
the solution at a time $t>0$ is given by the exponential of $tA$ applied to the initial vector
$$
y(t)=\exp(tA) y_0.
$$

( Applying the exponential on each matrix entry does not solve an ODE system in general.)

Remark: When $A$ is a diagonalizable matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n\in\mathbb{C}$ and eigenbasis $V\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, i.e.,
$A=V \text{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n) V^{-1}$,
the matrix exponential $\exp(A)$ as defined in \eqref{expA} can be written as
$$
exp(A)  = V \text{diag}(\exp(\lambda_1),\ldots,\exp(\lambda_n)) V^{-1}.
$$
Make use of the eigendecomposition of $A$ in \eqref{ODEA} to show that $\exp(tA)$ yields a solution of the ODE system.